# MySQL Insert if not exist, otherwise, return the id

Tags: mysql

I have the following query;

```
INSERT INTO table (full_name)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'John') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE full_name = 'John'
) LIMIT 1;

SELECT id FROM table WHERE full_name = 'John';
```

It works, but as you can see, the query is divided into two. Can it be done in a single query only?

I want to insert a new `full_name` if it doesn't exist. Otherwise, return the `id` of existing `full_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using concatenation.

```
$sql = INSERT INTO table (full_name)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'John') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE full_name = 'John'
) LIMIT 1;

$sql .= SELECT id FROM table WHERE full_name = 'John';
```